# Finding Arithmetic Mean of Subarrays Efficiently in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, computer-science

I am trying to find number of ways o calculate arithmetic mean of a subarray of an array.
It boils down to this; given an array X and an integer S, how many contiguous fragments of X has arithmetic mean equal to S?

For instance, given  X=[5,3,6,2] and S=4 result is 3. [5,3] , [6,2] and [5,3,6,2] has the mean 4.

> X might have up to 100.000 elements. Each value of X is an integer in
> range of {-1.000.000.000,+1.000.000.000}. So is S.
> We don't round the arithmetic mean found.

My code below(on Java) works for small set of data but it is not efficient. O(n^2).

```
public static int returnSubsequenceCount(int[] X, int S) {
        int counter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < X.length; i++) {
            int[] dpSum = new int[X.length];

            dpSum[i] = X[i];

            if (X[i] == S) {
                counter++;
            }

            for (int j = i + 1; j < X.length; j++) {
                int sum = dpSum[j - 1] + X[j];

                dpSum[j] = sum;

                if ((double) sum / (j - i + 1) == S) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }
```

Comment: Utilize a tree. You can go through the array once, put each element in a tree. Each node of the tree should hold the value + mean of the path of values to reach the node. In the end, all paths to the leaves with mean = S are the solution. Runtime O(n log n).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it [belongs on Software Recommendations.SE, as per this meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322252/where-can-i-ask-for-algorithm-recommendations).

Comment: It is worth to specify - what do you mean by `subsequence`. Usually continuous pieces of array are called subarrays while subsequence might be non-continuous. Your code addresses continuous subarrays.

Comment: What's the source of this problem?

Comment: @Polygnome  Can you elaborate on "mean of the path of values to reach the node"?
For each node there should be many paths reaching to self so many mean values right?

Comment: @selman https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean In a *tree*, there is exactly one path from the root to each node. Otherwise, its not a tree.

Comment: @Polygnome  
About "Each node of the tree should hold the value + mean of the path of values to reach the node" : Each node has many paths reaching to it. Given X=[5,3,6,2] and a Node holds the value 6,there are many paths reaching to that node. For instance one is [5,3,6] other is [3,6] and another is just [6]. 
So how does a node holds all the arithmetic mean values for those?

Comment: @selman By definition, a node in a tree can only be reached by one path from the node. Otherwise, its not a tree, but a directed graph.

Comment: @Polygnome 
in this case utilizing a tree is not a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 8):

There's a trick here to obtain an `O(n)` algorithm:

```
average = (A[i] + A[i+1] ... + A[j]) / (j - i + 1)

average * (j - i + 1) = A[i] + A[i+1]...+ A[j]
```

Notice that since `average` is now multiplied by exactly the number of elements on the right side of the equation, we can subtract the average *once* for each one of the elements:

```
0 = (A[i]-average) + (A[i+1]-average) ... + (A[j]-average)
```

Finding contiguous sums that equal zero can be done by examining prefix sums. For each rightmost element (`A[j]-average`), we want to add the number of times we've seen the same prefix sum before. We make an adjustment for prefix sum 0 so as to count the full length of the array prefix if applicable:

```
2 1 3, avg 2

2-2 = 0    ps = 0    count = 1 (1 for the full array prefix)
1-2 = -1   ps = -1
3-2 = 1    ps = 0    count = 2 (1 for index 0 and 1 for the full array prefix)

                     total = 3
```

Comment: Intriguing! Can you please clarify how you determine "the number of times we've seen the same prefix sum before"? The prefix sums can be on the order of billions. I could not think of anything except a hash table, as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @CătălinFrâncu the number of prefix sums cannot be greater than O(n). Example: [1, 2, -3, 2, - 2, 4, -1], prefix sums: [1, 3, 0, 2, 0, 4, 3], the contiguous sums between identical prefix values, `(0,0] 2 - 2 = 0, and (3, 3] -3 + 2 - 2 + 4 - 1 = 0`, are zeros. Each rightmost prefix can be paired with as many equal prefixes we find to its left (with a special case for the full length prefix) to form contiguous sums zero. All we have to do is count how many prefixes with value, `v`, we have seen so far as we iterate to the right. We can use a hash table to store them.

Comment: Brilliant idea from using prefix sum and dictionary to check any seen of previous sum before.

Comment: how smart idea this is

Answer (score 5):

I will use 1-based indexing for this algorithm. This feels like one of those cases where it is OK.

Let `P` be the partial sums array, that is `P[0] = 0` and `P[i] = X[1] + ... + X[i]`. Furthermore, let `Q[i] = P[i] - S * i`. For example,

```
i     0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
-----------------------------------
X         5   3   6   2   5   5   2
P     0   5   8  14  16  21  26  28
Q     0   1   0   2   0   1   2   0
```

What does it mean that the average of `[i,j]` (including `i` and `j`) is `S`? With the notations above, it can be written as

```
(P[j] - P[i - 1]) / (j - i + 1) = S     ==>
P[j] - P[i - 1] = S * (j - i + 1)       ==>
P[j] - P[i - 1] = S * j - S * (i - 1)   ==>
P[j] - S * j = P[i - 1] - S * (i - 1)   ==>
Q[j] = Q[i - 1]
```

This means that any pair of equal values in `Q` corresponds to a range of average `S`. For example, the two values of 1 in `Q` correspond to the range [3, 6, 2, 5]. The four values of 0 in `Q` give rise to six ranges of average `S=4`: [5,3], [6,2], [5,5,2], [5,3,6,2], [6,2,5,5,2] and [5,3,6,2,5,5,2].

Therefore the following algorithm also runs in `O(n log n)`, the same as @Polygnome's comment, but should be considerably easier to implement:

- calculate Q;
- sort Q;
- for every batch of `k` equal values in `Q`, add `k * (k - 1) / 2` to the answer;
- return the answer.

This can be reduced to `O(n)` using a hash table or if the range of the values in `Q` is small enough to allow counting sort.

Comment: We do not need counting or any kind of sort. We can accomplish this in `O(n)` time regardless of element range.

Answer (score 2):

Heres a Java solution with prefix sums, also using feedback from this thread.

```
import java.util.*;

        public static int returnSubsequenceCount(int[] X, int S)
    {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> prefixes = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        int result = 0;
        int[] P = new int[X.length + 1];
        prefixes.put(0, 1);

        int[] Q = new int[X.length + 1];
        P[0] = 0;
        Q[0] = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < X.length + 1; i++)
        {
            P[i] = P[i - 1] + X[i - 1];
            Q[i] = P[i] - S * i;

            if (!prefixes.containsKey(Q[i]))
            {
                prefixes.put(Q[i], 1);
            }
            else
            {
                Integer temp=prefixes.get(Q[i]);
                temp++;
                prefixes.put(Q[i],temp);

            }

        }

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : prefixes.entrySet())
        {
            int value = entry.getValue();
            result += value * (value - 1) / 2;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found explanation by [Cătălin Frâncu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6022817/c%C4%83t%C4%83lin-fr%C3%A2ncu) extremely clear and concise. Here is the code with tests (Scala):

```
object T3 {
  def numOfSubArraysWithMean(a: Array[Int], s: Int): Int =
    a.lazyZip(LazyList from 1)
      .foldLeft((0, List(0))) { case ((pi, q), (ai, i)) =>
        val pi2 = pi + ai
        val qi = pi2 - s * i
        (pi2, qi :: q)
      }._2
      .groupMapReduce(identity)(_=>1)(_+_)
      .withFilter { case (_, v) => v > 1 }
      .map { case (_, v) => v * (v - 1) / 2 }
      .sum
}

class T3Spec extends AnyFunSpec with Matchers {
  import T3._
  def a[A: ClassTag](aa: A*): Array[A] = aa.toArray
  it("a") {
    val data = Seq(
      (a(5,3,6,2,5,5,2),4) -> 8,
      (a(5,3,6,2,5),4) -> 4,
      (a(5,3,6,2,5,3),4) -> 7,
      (a(5,3,6,2),4) -> 3,
      (a(5,3,6,2,4),4) -> 6,
      (a(2,1,3,7,2,2,1,3),2) -> 9,
      (a(0,8,1,7,2,6,3,5),4) -> 10,
      (a(2,2,3,4,1,1),2) -> 4,
      (a(2,2,2,2,2,2),2) -> 21,
      (a(2,2,2,2),2) -> 10,
    )
    for {
      ((a, s), r) <- data
    } numOfSubArraysWithMean(a, s) shouldEqual r
  }
}
```

In most cases, `N` vs `NlogN` doesn't matter. But `N^2` is a problem

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin version

```
fun solution(A: IntArray, S: Int): Int {
    return A.asSequence()
        .runningFold(0) { acc, i -> acc + i }
        .map { ((it % S) + S) % S }
        .groupingBy { it }
        .eachCount()
        .values
        .sumOf { it * (it - 1) / 2 }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This is how to do it in python, the key is to produce Powerset

```
def mean_subsequence(array: list, mean: int) -> int:
result = 0
powerset = [[]]

for num in array:
    len_ = len(powerset)
    for i in range(len_):
        subsequent = powerset[i]
        #check the mean
        tmp = [num] + subsequent
        if tmp != [] and sum(tmp) / len(tmp) == mean:
            result += 1
        #update power set
        powerset.appened([num] + subsequent)
        
return result
```